# hook_form_FORMID_alter select list default value

Tags: forms, views

I created a custom module to override some fields in an exposed form created by views. One of the filters is the between filter on a number field. The between filter produces min and max fields for every field in the form. What I want to do is replace the min and max text fields with lists of integers that the user can select from. Where I am stuck at is the default value of the lists. I keep getting the following message:
"An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."
Below is a snippet from my module file:

```
$sale_price_min_options=array(
  'All'=>t('-Any'),
  10000=>'10000',
  20000=>'20000',
  30000=>'30000',
  40000=>'40000',
  50000=>'50000',
  60000=>'60000',
  70000=>'70000'
);


$form['field_sale_price_value']['min']=array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#options' => $sale_price_min_options,
          '#default_value' => "",
      );
      $form['field_sale_price_value']['max']=array(
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#options' => $sale_price_min_options,
                '#default_value' => 70000,
            );
```

Please let me know where did I go wrong. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change 'All' to ''. The key should be blank. The default value is not matching the option list.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @kevin, using your approach I get the first choice as blank. What I want is have one of the items chosen by default.